# Query Mongo Database for Records on a Single Day

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

My requirement is a simple one. I have some Mongo documents which contain a `startTime` (a `DateTime` field) and I want to query the containing collection for all of the documents that have a `startTime` on a particular day.

For example, I want all documents which have a date "22/10/2015", I don't care about the time component, I just want all documents that have that date.

I have written the following method to *attempt* to do this

```
public static async Task<List<uint>> DateRangeToEventIDAdapter(
    MongoClient client, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int? limit, 
    IProgress<string> progress, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (startDate == endDate)
        endDate = endDate.AddDays(1.0);

    var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
    var filter = filterBuilder.Gte(
        MatchDetailsFields.START_TIME, BsonDateTime.Create(startDate.ToUniversalTime()));
    filter = filterBuilder.And(filter, filterBuilder.Lte(MatchDetailsFields.START_TIME,
        BsonDateTime.Create(endDate.ToUniversalTime())));

   // Use Filter to get collection here...
}
```

[using C# Driver 2.0]. My problem case is when `startDate == endDate`, if I just use `Eq.` this returns zero records. So I attempt to add 24 hours to the time of the `startDate` for the `endDate` and then use `.Lte` and `.Gte` - this dow not work and returns both days.

This seems SOOOOO simple, but yet I can get Mongo to return what I want. What filter should I be using to retrieve all documents that occur on a specified day?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (you should be using Lt and not Lte):

```
var theDay = new DateTime(2015,10,22).ToUniversalTime();

var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Gte(  "startTime" , theDay ) &
             builder.Lt( "startTime", theDay.AddDays(1) ) ;

var list = await col.Find( filter ).ToListAsync();
```

You might code it as:

```
endDate = endDate.Date.AddDays(1);
```